# How can i write this C code snippet as per MATLAB syntax?

Tags: c, matlab, for-loop

```
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    for(i=0,k=j;i<=j && k<=j; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", Mat[k][i]);
        k--;
    }
}
```

There's some difference in the 'for loop' syntax between the two languages which is troubling me... please help

Comment: What output do you expect? What are you getting instead? What is the declaration of `Mat`? `i`, `j` and `k` are of type `int`? Syntactically, this code is correct.

Comment: `k` is always less than `j` in inner loop

Comment: @P0W: yeah but i need to check the value of `k` in every iteration of inner loop as i am decreasing the value of k in the end

Comment: @mafso Mat is a 2D array. Its a matrix. `i`,`j` & `k` are of type `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for j = 1:n % Starts from 1 to n
   k = j;
   % k is always less than j in your inner loop
   for i = 1:j
      fprintf("%d", Mat(k, i) ); % Assuming int for Mat elements
      k = k - 1 ;
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need..

```
for j = 1:n
    for i = 1:j && k = j:-1:1      
      //todo
    end
end
```

Comment: If `(j=0; j<n; j++)` becomes `j = 1:n`, then `(i=0; i<=j; i++)` cannot become `i = 1:j`, I think? I'm not used to Matlab, though, maybe I'm doing a one-off mistake.

Comment: Are you referring (j+1)? i thought there was mistake in his for loop it should have been i<j.. Anything else?

Comment: @mafso yeah may be you're right.... i dont think `i=1:j` is appropriate in this case